# Node-RED and REST APIs with resource id's

Tags: rest, wildcard, node-red

I'm trying to use Node-RED to develop a REST based API.  For example, a GET would be:

http://myurl.com/widgets/"widget-id"

where "widget-id" would be 123.  I can get this to work using query strings.  However, I can't seem to figure out what to put on the http input node to allow a resource id to get passed.  Am I missing something obvious?  Any ideas on what I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer is nearly right, it just needs tweaking for Node-RED

If you set the URL in the **HTTP Input** node to `/widget/:id`

you can access the widget id in a function node linked to the **HTTP Input** node as follows:

```
var id = msg.req.params.id;
```

Comment: The :id was the part that I was missing.  I've got it running.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you get all widgets:

```
router.get('/widgets/', function(data){});
```

if only one item(for example - 123):

```
router.get('/widgets/:id(\\d+)', function(data){});
```

in you're browser or if you using POSTMAN enter http url: http://youredomain.com/widgets/or http://youredomain.com/widgets/123

Comment: This answer is for express, the OP is specifically asking about how to do with with Node-RED